# Rights Management on MySQL: Only execute Stored Procedures, no further access on database

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, rights-management

i´m developing a webbased interface communication via mysql database. For a trade fair i need to hand over the interface and database to a customer. Every communication with the database is encapsulated via stored procedures. Therefore i would like to creat a user who only has the right to execute stored procedures but no more rights so that nobody can see the details of the database...

Is this possible with mysql 5.1? Is this possible at all?

Does anyone has a different solution to limit access to mysql databases which will be given to other people?

Thanks in advance and kind regards

Solick